# Local virtualhost takes too long to load on MAMP

Tags: localhost, virtual-host, mamp

I have a virtualhost "myhost.local" configured in MAMP

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       myhost.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
#::1            localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

It worked fine.

After I upgraded my OS to the latest version (Lion), something changed because now Firefox/Chrome take a few seconds to find the myhost.local domain. It's very annoying to develop in these conditions.

It only happens if the domain has not been visited after some seconds (cache?) - any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `*.local` domain was in conflict with Multicast DNS feature of Bonjour.

I changed my virtualhost name and it worked fine.

More information:

> - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3473
> - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2385